# Your application requires X, but Microsoft Azure App only supports X when deploying a WebApp

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have a small application which has an Anuglar 8 WebApp and .Net Core 3.0 API in the same project. When I try to deploy it to Azure I get the following:

[image: error]

So far I have tried deploying the project as a Self-Contained App but I get `HTTP Error 500.30`, which is the same error I got previously when I try to access the application.

I also double-checked all my connection settings in `appsettings` and everything seems fine (even compared them to an application which I have in production running .net core 2.2.6)

Comment: Please share your startup file and how you make self-deployment app

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my problem. I am still getting the confusing error however, the application runs just fine. The issue was in the following line in the startup file - `configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist` should have been 
`ClientApp/dist/myapp` instead.
I did not realize the way my angular.json was setup it was creating an extra folder.